# Obtaining parameters for a scaled data set

Tags: distributions, levy-distribution

I have a levy distribution parameters obtained for a set of data. I want to know an easy way to calculate the parameters for a new data set obtained by multiplying all the elements in the initial data set by a constant(say C).

$new data = old data * C$

parameters for the old data 
$\alpha_1$ , $\beta_1$, $\gamma_1$ and $\delta_1$

wants to know parameters for new data
$\alpha_2$, $\beta_2$, $\gamma_2$ and $\delta_2$